# Check json api for specific values and run function (from front end)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I have an API that gets called on my site.    api.foo.com that contains unique IDs and their attributes.

```
uniqueID: "X1111",
IsActive: "true",
myCode: "E"


uniqueID: "X2222",
IsActive: "true",
myCode: "D"
```

Using a front end CMS, is there a way I can ping the API via javascript/jquery and run a function?  Ultimately:

1. Reference api.foo.com on page load
2. Find all IDs where myCode =  E
3. Do something on the page

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make a GET request to your API:

```
var root = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
var myUserIdOne = [];
$.ajax({
  url: root + '/posts/1',
  method: 'GET'
}).then(function(data) {
if (userId == 1)
    myUserIdOne.push(data);
});
```